# FragmentTabHost with DrawerLayout, fragment is not showing after replacing the content

Tags: fragment-tab-host

i am using fragmenttabhost with drawer layout (containing settings button). there are 4 tabs in fragmenttabhost. NavigationView in drawer layout that contains 4 buttons. In my activity where fragmenttabhost is placed at bottom, and above is FrameLayout for containing the content of the tab. Now my problem is, lets suppose my application starts and by default tab at 0 index "home" is selected, i opened the drawer and click on settings button and i have placed the settings fragment in framelayout, which hold the tab's content. now when i close the drawer and click again on the tab which is at 0 index "home" , its view is not showing up.

any help would be thankful.